# Using AutoCompleteTextView from a database column which may have repeated entries

Tags: java, android, sqlite, autocomplete, textview

How can I provide suggestions for an AutoCompleteTextView from a column in a database table which may have some values repeated?

http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/11/android-autocompletetextview-sqlite-and-dependent-fields/

http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/11/android-simpler-autocompletetextview-with-simplecursoradapter/

In learning how to use AutoCompleteTextView, I ran across the above two blog articles. These are great for an introduction but don't quite solve my problem. I want to provide the distinct values of a column from my database as the suggestions for a AutoCompleteTextView in my app. When I implement the code from the above two examples, I get repeated suggestions in my list. Trying to use the `DISTINCT` keyword in my query doesn't work because `CursorAdapter` requires an `_id` field in the returned results. Since each row has its own `_id`, the repeated values are not eliminated.

I am considering creating a separate lookup table for the values. This has the benefit of normalizing my data as well as providing easy access to the distinct values to suggest for entries. For one of my AutoCompleteTextViews, I think this will work well because there are most likely only 4 or 5 different values that will be used. For another, it might not work as well because I'm not sure how many distinct values there will be in a large data set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, bar TEXT);
```

And want to select only one `_id` for each distinct `bar` you can use:

```
SELECT _id, bar FROM Foo GROUP BY bar;
```

Comment: I don't want the `_id` at all (other than to satisfy CursorAdapter). In your example, ultimately I only care about the values in `bar`. I'll try the `GROUP BY` and see how that works.

Comment: This appears to work. Since you were the first to the punch, I am accepting your answer.

Answer (score 2):

try using GROUP BY when you do the sqlite select query... and group by the column name...
i.e.

```
 SELECT keyword FROM mytable GROUP BY keyword
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this is not over kill, but why not try a subquery?

```
select _id, bar 
from Foo 
where bar in (
    select distinct bar
    from Foo
);
```

The inner query would return all the distinct values in 'bar', and then the outer query will match all these values with the corresponding '_id'.

Comment: This will still select all the duplicate `bar` values.

Comment: This will still return *every* row that has a given value in the `bar` field, not just one of them.